# How can I custom UITableViewCell like Twitter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I found that the iPad twitter.app UITableViewCell's border have two pixel line, it looks beautiful and professional,how can I do that? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: You should probably go back and accept some answers on your previous questions. It'll make people more willing to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because `UITableViewCell` inherits from `UIView`, a cell has a content view. You can add your own subviews (the labels and textfields) to that `contentView` and lay them out programmatically or using the Interface Builder.

There are a lot of online tutorials on how to accomplish that. Just search with google for "uitableviewcell interface builder tutorial".

Check out this pretty good tutorial [`Custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder`](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/).

Comment: Okay,I'll try now.Thank you Srikar!

Answer (score 2):

Finally,I customed UITableViewCell use code,and I think it looks well. : )

MenuViewController.m file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self.view setFrame:frame]; 

        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [_tableView setDelegate:self];
        [_tableView setDataSource:self];
        [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

        UIView* footerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 1)];
        [_tableView setTableFooterView:footerView];
        [footerView release];        

        [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    DoubleSeparatorCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[DoubleSeparatorCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    NSString *text;
    UIColor *upperLineColor,*lowerLineColor,*viewColor;

    upperLineColor = RGBA(255, 255, 255, 30);
    lowerLineColor = RGBA(0, 0, 0, 50);
    viewColor = RGBA(0,0,0,5);

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
    } else if ([indexPath row] == 1) {
        text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
    } else if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
        text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
    } else {
        text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
    }
    [cell.textLabel setText:text];
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:RGBA(170, 170, 170, 100)];
    [cell.textLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

    [cell.upperLine setBackgroundColor:upperLineColor];
    [cell.lowerLine setBackgroundColor:lowerLineColor];
    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:viewColor];

    return cell;
}
```

DoubleSeparatorCell.h

```
@interface DoubleSeparatorCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIView *upperLine;
    UIView *lowerLine;
}
@property (nonatomic ,retain) UIView *upperLine;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) UIView *lowerLine;
@end
```

DoubleSeparatorCell.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.upperLine = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.lowerLine = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.upperLine];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.lowerLine];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self.upperLine setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    [self.lowerLine setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.contentView.frame.size.height - 1, self.frame.size.width, 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Srikar has already showed you the right path. By the way i just want to add the following:

You can cutomize your cell programmatically which can be done by inheriting the native class UITableViewCell.

Then by, create the instance of table view cell class and add it to the UITableView.

Now the cell is yours.

**Happy Coding**,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

I'd point out that those cells you screenshot appear to have a light gray top border of 1 point and a dark gray bottom border of 1 point (or maybe they are pixels - sorry my eyes aren't that good :-) ).

So it may be kind of a hack (go on, savage me people), but you could:

1. Create a UILabel topBorder with frame CGRect(0,0,cell.contentView.frame.size,width,1)
2. Create a UILabel bottomBorder with frame CGRect (0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1,cell.contentView.frame.size.width,1)
3. Set color of topBorder to UIColor lightGrayColor (or tweak for exact colors)
4. Set color of bottomBorder to UIColor darkGrayColor (ditto)
5. Add both subViews to cell.contentView

Note that you do not have to subclass UITableCellView - simply add these steps to your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method and they will appear.

Enjoy,

Damien

Answer (score 0):

Override drawRect method and draw lines as you need.

```c
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
      CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
      CGContextRef context      = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [topColor CGColor]);
      // border top
      CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width, bounds.origin.y);
      CGContextStrokePath(context); 
      // border bottom
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
      CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [lowerColor CGColor]);

      CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y+1);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.origin.x+bounds.size.width, bounds.origin.y+1);

      CGContextStrokePath(context); 
}
```